# Tensorboard: File system scheme gs not implemented

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, tensorboard

I am not able to connect `tensorboard` to my Google Cloud Platform as I am facing the following error:

**Command that I am running:**

`gcloud auth application-default login`
`tensorboard --logdir=gs://mybucket_which_contains_train_and_eval_directories`

**Stacktrace:**

```
Exception in thread Reloader:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python\python35\lib\threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()
  File "c:\python\python35\lib\threading.py", line 862, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "c:\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\backend\application.py", line 327, in _reload_forever
reload_multiplexer(multiplexer, path_to_run)
  File "c:\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\backend\application.py", line 299, in reload_multiplexer
multiplexer.AddRunsFromDirectory(path, name)
  File "c:\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\backend\event_processing\event_multiplexer.py", line 175, in AddRunsFromDirectory
for subdir in GetLogdirSubdirectories(path):
  File "c:\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\backend\event_processing\event_multiplexer.py", line 439, in GetLogdirSubdirectories
if tf.gfile.Exists(path) and not tf.gfile.IsDirectory(path):
  File "c:\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 252, in file_exists
pywrap_tensorflow.FileExists(compat.as_bytes(filename), status)
  File "c:\python\python35\lib\contextlib.py", line 66, in __exit__
next(self.gen)
  File "c:\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 466, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnimplementedError: File system scheme gs not implemented`
```

**OS Platform and Distribution (e.g., Linux Ubuntu 16.04):**
`Windows 10`

**TensorFlow installed from (source or binary):**
`pip3 install tensorflow`

**TensorFlow version (use command below):**
`1.3.0`

**Tensorboard version:**
`0.1.4`

**Python version:**
`3.5.2`

Comment: it seems tensorboard doesn't support gs file system yet. One workaround is to login first then run tensorboard

Comment: It does support gs, at least for linux

Comment: And what do you mean by 'Login first'? I had already logged in as mentioned in my question itself

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems like tensorflow doesn't support `gs` filesystem for windows yet. Follow the below git issues for the same:

- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/11280
- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/429

Comment: Is there any solution? This is such a silly issue to have and renders me unable to run code that uses the `tensorflow-datasets` package..